# Add custom platform version

Tags: cordova

I am using the last version of Cordova. But I want use android 4.0.0.

`> cordova platform list`

```
Installed platforms:
  android 7.0.0
  browser 5.0.3
  ios 4.5.4
Available platforms:
  osx ~4.0.1
  windows ~5.0.0
  www ^3.12.0
```

`> cordova platform add android@4.0.0`

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@4.0.0
Adding android project...
Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. (Does not appear to implement platform Api.)
Error: Package name must look like: com.company.Name
```

How can I add android 4.0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmmm very simple.

according to [this page](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html) i must install cordova 6.0.0 and sdk tools 25.2.3.

each version of cordova has some api(android version).